# Solr multivalued fields

Tags: solr, indexing

We are currently working on migrating from Lucene to Solr and we're having a couple of issues with our index data. There hasn't been any code changes so we're assuming it is stemming from the indexed data. We have a couple of multivalued field

```
<field name="indexname_s" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="true" />
```

This field is supposed to be multivalued, which as you can see, it is. However, I was wondering if that `_s` postfix would have an effect of any sort. The field contains a string collection, which I know should be postfixed with `_sm`. Does the postfix really affect data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

Or rather, yes, it can do.

If the fields are not defined in the `schema.xml`, SOLR will map field types based on patterns in the field name. Sort of like *convention over configuration*.

Some common conventions:

[image]

Information sourced from: [Solr Tutorial](http://yonik.com/solr-tutorial/) by [@lucene_solr](https://twitter.com/lucene_solr).

Comment: Its important to remember that it does, because in the Schema.xml file that Sitecore generates, it creates a set of wildcard fields. Eg. the multi-valued string field is `<dynamicField name="*_sm" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />`. So have a look at your schema xml file for a list of the naming conventions. If you don't want to use the suffix - you could just add the field to your schema.xml for more control.